# What is the android lockscreen widget lifecycle?

Tags: android, widget

I have an app widget and enabled it as a lockscreen widget by adding "keyguard" to the widgetCategory attribute of the app widget provider xml.  I added a debug view to my widget to display a timestamp every time onUpdate is called.

I noticed that the lock screen widget sometimes gets updated several minutes before the home screen widgets do, even though my onUpdate iterates through all my widget instances.  During these times, I noticed that my debug view shows no update in the timestamp for my lock screen widget instance, even though the data has been updated.

This leads me to believe some other callback is being invoked specifically for the lockscreen instance that is not for the home screen widget instances.  **What is the sequence of callbacks invoked for the lockscreen widget?**

My second question is, with my device plugged in and log messages added in my code, **why don't I see logcat messages consistently(android studio recognizes my device)**.

Additional details: KitKat 4.4.4, updatePeriodMillis in app widget provider is set to the minimum 30 minutes.